# What is the best thing to do with lemons?

Tags: internal-consistency, flora, survival, agriculture

A person has been granted access to non-finite amount of lemons that simply appear at random intervals. No matter what they do, they can't escape these deliveries of lemons. How can they most benefit from the non-finite amount of lemons at their disposal?

Essentially, if life gives one lemons, should they make lemonade? If not, what is the most proftable course of action to take when given lemons?

Comment: You can produce small amounts of electricity using lemons, but you'll also need zinc and copper for each lemon battery.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery

Comment: It's obvious. Make [combustible lemons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dt6iTwVIiMM)! What else?

Comment: @AndyD273 probably my favorite line in all of portal

Comment: Cant' believe no one else has mentioned it, but if life gives you lemons, find someone who life has given tequila and....

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986)...

Comment: First life gives me lemons then people vote to close my question? Ugh, I guess there is no use in crying over spilled lemonade.

Comment: How can I request the off-topic hold to be re-reviewed?

Comment: You can check [this page](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for more details. The short of it is, if you edit the question, it will enter a moderation queue to be reopened. To see how to edit it to fit better, see (as stated above) [Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3300/49). I wondered briefly if this might be more appropriate to [Writers SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) but [apparently not](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/875/writers-se-on-topic-summary).

Answer (score 6):

### Start the Lemon Head Power Supply

[image]

[Lemon batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery) are used in small amounts to power lights in order to teach chemical properties to children. In extreme bulk (in the case of your gift), they could theoretically used to power a small house; imagine free power! It is unlikely you could power anything more than a house or electric car but no one can deny that free power is quite beneficial.

On problem is that you also will need zinc and copper for each lemon battery, so you might have to *borrow* some supplies to find your generator. If all else fails you can make **no pulp** lemonade.

Comment: each lemon occupies space, why don't just use the juice instead? you would need only one batter.

Comment: @淡紅色鼠 what do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

Citric Acid is used in many different applications, from cleaning to food. While you could go in for specifically producing lemon-based snacks or industrial cleaner, a much more efficient use of your time might be in simply producing a form of citric acid that can then be used by a host of industries.

However, anything you make will require other things in order to produce what you want whether it be batteries, lemonade or citric acid.

The biggest benefit you could reap without any outlay of cost (except storage) would be to sell them to interested parties/ industries.

Answer (score 4):

US lemon production runs about 700,000 to 800,000 tonnes per year, depending on your source. Since your production costs are zero, you should be able effectively to take over the entire US lemon market. There will be startup costs involved in building processing plants (unless you already live in Florida or California), but that should be easily produced, given your cost advantage. Then, you can do everything that is already done with lemons.

Of course, if your post was correct that you only get a paltry few thousand at a time, and at random intervals at that, it won't be worth anyone's time and effort to take advantage of your good fortune. Instead, sell them to local supermarkets, who can absorb these small amounts.